# Javascript make visible and add multiple divs on click-Almost working now

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to use Javascript to to add a  section to a page when  a button is clicked. I can't get this to work though. My codepen is https://codepen.io/anon_guy/pen/VMZWWW

(Thanks for the help I've gotten it close to where I want it, however The element is still visible initially, it should be hidden but if I set display to none in CSS the JS doesn't change it. The code has changed quite a bit here is what I've got going currently

**HTML :**

```
 <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-event" class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label>name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="name" placeholder="name" id="name" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label>address</label>
        <input type="text" name="address" value="address" placeholder="address" id="address" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label>phone</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" value="phone" placeholder="phone" id="phone" class="form-control" />
        <div class="text-danger"></div>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="add_component">
    <button id='launch'>Add Component</button>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="panel panel-default " id="addon">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-event" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <label>component</label>
          <iv>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>iv>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS :**

```
 document.getElementById('launch').onclick = function() {
    var addOnDiv = document.getElementById('addon');

    if (addOnDiv.style.display === 'none') {
      addOnDiv.style.display = 'block';
    } else {

      var clonedNode = addOnDiv.cloneNode(true);
      addOnDiv.appendChild( clonedNode );      
    }
  }
```

**CSS :**

```
button {
  float: right;
  margin: 30px;
}

.panel-body {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background: azure;
}
#addon{
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: Your JavaScript references an element with the ID of "add_component", but your HTML only has an element with that class. Consequently, the element with the ID is not found and JavaScript "...cannot set property 'onclick' of null".

Comment: awesome thanks man I switched the getElementyId('show/hide') and that worked. Im confused on what I do next because I want this element to show up, but when the button is pressed again I want another copy of that element to show up, but I dont want the first element that showed up to disappear. So I need to figure out  how to have the element stay hidden until the first click and then after that every click just adds another section.

Answer (score 3):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/36990/)**.

You could set the display to none by default then change it to block when you click the first time, else clone the element container and append it :

```
document.getElementById('show/hide').onclick = function() {
  var divTest = document.getElementById('addon');

  if (divTest.style.display === 'none') {
    divTest.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    var new_line = divTest.querySelector('.col-sm-6').cloneNode(true);
    divTest.querySelector('.panel-body').appendChild( new_line );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Be aware that if you clone the pre-existing node, you'll need to make sure that the new cloned node(s) have `id`'s that differ from the originals.

Comment: Thanks for your intervention @scott , but the cloned container doesn't have no id's in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You should show and hide the div with id "addon" for the first time. 
On the subsequent clicks clone the node using [CloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)method.

The append it to the wrapper.

```js
document.getElementById('show/hide').onclick = function() {
    var addOnDiv = document.getElementById('addon');
  
    if (addOnDiv.style.display === 'none') {
      addOnDiv.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
    
      var clonedNode = addOnDiv.querySelector('.col-sm-6').cloneNode(true);
      addOnDiv.querySelector('.panel-body').appendChild( clonedNode );
      
      
    }
  }
```

```css
button {
  float: right;
  margin: 30px;
}

.panel-body {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background: azure;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-event" class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label>name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="name" placeholder="name" id="name" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label>address</label>
        <input type="text" name="address" value="address" placeholder="address" id="address" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <label>phone</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" value="phone" placeholder="phone" id="phone" class="form-control" />
        <div class="text-danger"></div>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="add_component">
    <a href='#' id="show/hide">
      <h3>Add:</h3>
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="panel panel-default " id="addon">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-event" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <label>component</label>
          <input type="text" name="component" value="component" placeholder="component" id="component" class="form-control" />
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have made some changes to HTML as well.

- You need not have multiple form elements. You are just specifying id on one form element and trying to submit the inner one.
- Few tags were not properly closed.
- I have added a wrapper component around the second panel. This is done in case you want to duplicate the whole panel. You can remove this if you just want to replicate the form element as shown in code below.

Comment: actually that what I would like to do is add the whole wrapper element. However when i change the JS to: var clonedNode = addOnDiv.querySelector('#addon').cloneNode(true);
      addOnDiv.querySelector('.wrapper').appendChild( clonedNode );  it doesn't work. isn't #addon a child of wrapper? Im confused

Comment: Let me summarize this for you. 
You can simply clone whatever you need to replicate. using the cloneNode method. and the append it to the element where you want to show it.